# Как распарсить строку?

Tags: javascript

Привет. Есть строка, которая может иметь два состояния:
1) Просто число от 1 до 99. 
2) Число с текстом. Например, 1PC23.

Нужно определить, если в строке содержатся только числа. А если содержаться числа и буквы(1PC23), то нужно взять число до PC и числа после. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `.match(/\d+/g).join('')`

Comment: @Grundy то есть, эта штука просто убирает 'PC' и оставляет только цифры?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
s = "123s4564";
result = 0;
j = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
{
    var n = parseInt(s[i], 10); 
    if (s[i].match(/^[-\+]?\d+/) !== null) { 
        result = result * 10 + n; 
    }
}
document.write(result);
```

Comment: н-да, оказывается, есть способ и полегче)))